# How can I capture CTRL-BACKSPACE in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

I have an application which uses `PreviewKeyDown` to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> keystrokes (where `X` is any letter) along the lines of:

```
Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {
    switch (key) {
        case Key.A: keyStroke = 0x01; break;
        case Key.B: keyStroke = 0x02; break;
        :
```

Because there doesn't appear to be a keystroke for backspace, I'm capturing that in a `PreviewTextInput` (along with the non<kbd>CTRL</kbd> keystrokes so as to avoid trying to map keys to characters manually):

```
private void Window_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
    Char ch = e.Text.ToCharArray()[0];
    if ((ch >= (Char)0x01) && (ch <= (Char)0x7e)) {
        // Do something with character.
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to capture the user pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>. I'm at a loss since the `PreviewKeyDown` doesn't seem to know about backspace and the `TextCompositionEventArgs` event doesn't seem to carry the keystates (like `CTRL` or `ALT`).

What's the best way (or, indeed, *any* way) to intercept <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>?

Comment: PreviewKeyDown detects backspace for me. If I add a Key.Back case to your switch statement it gets called like I would expect.

Comment: OK thanks. I added an answer. And yeah I'm sure the naming of that key has caught me out before as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect the backspace key you need to use the Key.Back value of the Key enumeration.

For instance:

```
Key key = (e.Key == Key.System ? e.SystemKey : e.Key);
if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {
    switch (key) {
        case Key.A: keyStroke = 0x01; break;
        case Key.B: keyStroke = 0x02; break;
        case Key.Back: // Do something
        break;
    }
}
```